# Don't show rank if dosn't exist in database id

Tags: mysql

how to not show rank if dosn't exist in database id in database

SQL code:

```
$query = "SELECT id, points, count(*)+1 AS rank FROM weekly_points 
          WHERE points > (SELECT points FROM weekly_points 
            WHERE id='".$account['id']."'
    )";
```

**Example query for id 15000 which doesn't exist:**

```
SELECT id,points,count(*)+1 as rank 
FROM weekly_points
WHERE points > (SELECT points FROM weekly_points WHERE id='15000')
-- output is rank 1 which is wrong
```

For id doesn't exist it shows rank 1 but I want to **not show the rank** or to be **9999999** or **last place**

**Sample,for rank to show**

uid------points-----> rank

1----------100-----5

2----------200------4

3----------1000---- 1

4----------300-----3

5----------400-----2

Comment: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: [The Hitchhiker's Guide to SQL Injection prevention](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection)

Comment: the issue is not about sql injection but about id if dosn't exist on database to show something else , but thanks for telling me how to prevent sql injection

Comment: Can you add some sample data of what your current query is returning right now and what you expect to get?

Comment: @Shidersz Yes i can, for example if we take id 15000 which dosnt exist is giving me **rank 1** i expected to not show becuse it dosnt exist on database or to show **last place** mabye could be 99999

Comment: @OrWeCanDoIT what I asked for is a set of data belonging to the `weekly_points` table and the output you are getting using your query. That sample you give is the same that was on your original question.

Comment: Your query doesn't look like a normal rank query. Why doesn't it have `GROUP BY id`? Which `id` and `points` is it supposed to return?

Comment: Can you show your table model

Comment: yes this should return  the rank of that uid example uid:1-- 1200 points -- rank 1,uid:2-- 300 points -- rank 2,uid:3-- 200 points -- rank 3

Comment: is `id` an integer? or a string? i.e. why are you using quotes for `id = '1500'`? I think you need to provide some **sample data** and the **expected result** from that sample . I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: id and points are in integer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC-BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted and subsequent attempts will get you banned. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/584192)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE` to return a default value when the ID doesn't exists.

```
SELECT id, points,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM weekly_points WHERE id='15000')
         THEN COUNT(*) + 1
         ELSE 999999
    END AS rnk
FROM weekly_points
WHERE points > (SELECT points FROM weekly_points WHERE id='15000')
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oNPzpDfyZ9KB4iweGM7hCA/1)

It doesn't really make sense to include `id` and `points` in this query. It will simply pick them from unpredictable rows that have higher points than the given ID.

Comment: this looks good i need to make sure and i will do some testing

Comment: if `id = '1500'` does not exist, the where clause subquery returns no row and the whole query returns no rows - or am I missing something?

Comment: @Used_By_Already A query that contains an aggregate function in the select list always returns a single row.

Comment: where is the aggregate function **in the where clause**?

Comment: yes, but the where clause still makes no sense, if id 1500 does not exist it returns null, and greater than null makes no sense

Comment: It doesn't matter, because we're not counting anything in that case, we just return `999999`. I've added a working demo.

Comment: That demo just shows as blank - but OK I get it now. Sorry

Comment: Click the Run button.

Comment: The answer of @Barmar is correct according to what you have said, unless you haven't figured your code logic yet.

Comment: I know that. See the first comment I made to the question.

Comment: @Barmar There is no run button visible. Perhaps you are logged-in? I am using Chrome as browser and have never seen that site's demos operate.  The URL redirects to the startup screen of that site. i.e. a blank canvas

Comment: @Used_By_Already No, I don't have an account there. I've only recently switched to it from sqlfiddle.com, but it seems to work fine for me with Chrome. The top toolbar has `Run Update Fork Load Example Collaborate`.

Comment: Side note: `RANK` is a reserved keyword as of MySQL 8+, because it corresponds to the rank analytic function.  You should avoid using `rank` as an alias.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Wow, that really sucks. There are probably thousands of sites that do rank queries, and probably most of them use that alias, which will break if they upgrade.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry again, no matter what I do that URL redirects to blank canvas, I suggest rextester.com or dbfiddle.uk (sqlfiddle is too unreliable imho)

Comment: @Used_By_Already Don't know what to tell you. Tim had no problem getting to my fiddle and forking it into his own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` as in the following query

```
SELECT id,points,count(*)+1 as rank 
  FROM weekly_points p1
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                  FROM weekly_points p2
                 WHERE p2.id='".$account['id']."'
                   AND p2.id=p1.id);
```

and then message to the screen that `$account['id']` doesn't exists as a valid ID, if it doesn't return a value for `id` column in the select list.

Comment: for others existing id is not getting the rank , it getting the last rank

Comment: @OrWeCanDoIT ok, reversely using `exists` may be a better way. In this case you can use those values in the select list, if they return.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest method is to add a `having` clause:

```
SELECT count(*)+1 as rank 
FROM weekly_points
WHERE points > (SELECT points FROM weekly_points WHERE id = '15000')
HAVING SUM(id = '15000') > 0;
```

You should not be selecting other columns, because they are not part of the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

The only interpretation of your question which makes any sense to me is that you want to find the points ranking of some `id`, e.g. `15000`.  In this case, we can try first computing the number of points for that `id` in a separate subquery, and then aggregating over the entire table, counting records which have more points than this particular `id`.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN wp2.points IS NOT NULL
         THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN wp1.points > wp2.points THEN 1 END) + 1
         ELSE 999999 END rnk
FROM weekly_points wp1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT points FROM weekly_points WHERE id = '15000') wp2;
```

Using the same @Barmar demo:

### Demo